# Como criar um evento em que quando usuario apertar a tecla de espaço aconteça algo?

Tags: jquery, funções, teclado, javascript-eventos

Por enquanto tenho somente esse trecho de código:

```
personagemPular.on("keyup",function(){
```

Queria trocar esse keyup por pressionar o espaço. E também estou usando um *text area* no HTML para receber as entradas do teclado, como faço pra receber de qualquer lugar da tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes adicionar esse auscultador de eventos ao `document` ou `window` para ouvir eventos na página toda e procurar pela propriedade que diz o código da tecla.

#### Exemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var codigoTecla = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
  var space = codigoTecla == 32;
  if (space) alert('O space foi pressionado!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta verificar se o event.keyCode foi 32, que é o espaço.

Clique no exemplo abaixo e aperte espaço

```js
$('#teste').keyup(function (e) { 
   var press = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
   if(press == 32)
   {
      alert('espaço foi pressionado');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Digite em mim<input type="text" id="teste"></input>
```